# How to increase MongoDB document default size?

Tags: mongodb, size

I'm having trouble storing more than 16 MB in MongoDB.
How to increase MongoDB document default size from 16 MB to 40MB?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum document size for a BSON document is 16MB, you cannot go over it.

You can utilise the GridFS objects to store objects bigger than the said size. Read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#bin.mongofiles).

.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use GridFS. it will store your document in small size document.
```

please follow  link. 
[GridFs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#bin.mongofiles)